# Flutter get result of BuildContext.findRenderObject

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to capture a `PNG` image of a Flutter Widget for use in a `MapBox` instance. The code requires that I detect when the Build process has completed, and the rendered area is ready to paint. Here is my `Widget`:

```
typedef void ImageCreatedCallback(UI.Image image);

class POIWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const POIWidget({Key key, this.poi, this.imageCreatedCallback})
      : super(key: key);
  final POI poi;
  final ImageCreatedCallback imageCreatedCallback;

  @override
  _POIWidgetState createState() => _POIWidgetState();
}

class _POIWidgetState extends State<POIWidget> {
  /**
   *  The only purpose of this widget is to provide an Image version of itself
   *  that can then be used in the MapBox map.
   */
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  Future<void> _capturePng() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

    if (boundary == null) {
      // print("Waiting for boundary to be painted.");
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      return _capturePng();
    }
    MediaQueryData queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double devicePixelRatio = queryData.devicePixelRatio;
    UI.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: devicePixelRatio);
    widget.imageCreatedCallback(image);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) async {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100))
            .then((_) => _capturePng());
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: globalKey,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Material(
          color: widget.poi.iconBackgroundColor,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: widget.poi.iconSize.size * 2,
            height: widget.poi.iconSize.size * 2,
            child: widget.poi.iconName != null
                ? IconManager.instance.getIconFromName(
                    widget.poi.iconName,
                    size: widget.poi.iconSize.size,
                    color: widget.poi.iconColor,
                  )
                : IconManager.instance.iconMapPin,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the `_capturePNG` method has this line:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
```

and then immediately afterwards I am testing to see if this is `null`. I think this is being ignored as it is not `null` but something else. It is, however, not what I need to create the image later on in the method.

I get this error message from this code:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (21697): #0      RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3089)
E/flutter (21697): #1      _POIWidgetState._capturePng (package:screens/map/widgets/POIWidget.dart:38)
E/flutter (21697): #2      _POIWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:screens/map/widgets/POIWidget.dart:48)
E/flutter (21697): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362)
E/flutter (21697): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265)
E/flutter (21697): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21697): #5      _POIWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:screens/map/widgets/POIWidget.dart:47)
E/flutter (21697): <asynchronous suspension>
```

How can I be sure the widget is built and the `RenderRepaintBoundary` is ready to be captured?

Comment: create a class that extends `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` and creates a custom `RenderProxyBox` - this custom `RenderProxyBox` should override `bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;` and inside its `void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) ` method grab the image by using `OffsetLayer ol = layer; ol.toImage(...)`

Comment: of course you have to call `ol.toImage(...)` after `super.paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset)` was called

Comment: So the problem here is that the widget has to be rendered onscreen before the image can be captured?

Comment: most likely, what do you have in `rendering/proxy_box.dart:3089`? is it `final OffsetLayer offsetLayer = layer! as OffsetLayer;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `RepaintBoundary` with  `Future.delayed` / `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` etc check how `RepaintBoundary` is implemented

after 5-10 minutes you could work out something like this:

```
class ImageGrab extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final Function(ByteData) onImageGrab;

  ImageGrab({Key key, @required Widget child, @required this.onImageGrab}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderImageGrab createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderImageGrab(onImageGrab);

  // TODO implement @override updateRenderObject ???
}

class RenderImageGrab extends RenderProxyBox {
  final Function(ByteData) onImageGrab;
  bool imageGrabbed;

  RenderImageGrab(this.onImageGrab);

  @override
  bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    print('=========== paint $size ===========');
    super.paint(context, offset);
    imageGrabbed ??= grabImage();
  }

  bool grabImage() {
    (layer as OffsetLayer)
      .toImage(Offset.zero & size)
      .then((image) => image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png))
      .then(onImageGrab);
    return true;
  }
}
```

the sample usage is:

```
child: ImageGrab(
  child: SomeWidgetToGrab(),
  onImageGrab: (data) => print('png image length: ${data.lengthInBytes}'),
),
```

**EDIT** strange thing: i was testing this code with a relatively complex widget and it was working fine but with simple `Container(color: Colors.red)` it throws `'package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart': Failed assertion: line 497 pos 12: 'picture != null': is not true.` exception, so the solution is to "futurize" `grabImage` method with:

```
  bool grabImage() {
    Future(_grabImage);
    return true;
  }

  _grabImage() {
    (layer as OffsetLayer)
      .toImage(Offset.zero & size)
      .then((image) => image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png))
      .then(onImageGrab);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I will test it out. I have solved the issue in the meantime using this package to detect visibility: https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector - but I can see how your extension is a lot more elegant.

Comment: your welcome, btw you could change `final Function(ByteData) onImageGrab` to `final Function(Uint8List) onImageGrab` as `Uint8List` is more convenient in various flutter classes (for example in `Image.memory` ctor or `File.writeAsBytes`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Widget needs to be visible and painted before you can grab an image, which is why the docs recommend you use a gesture event to initiate the image capture.

To solve my issue I used this library to detect visibility: https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

Updated widget code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as UI;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';
import 'package:weald_ar_trails/model/POI.dart';
import 'package:weald_ar_trails/utils/managers/IconManager.dart';

typedef void ImageCreatedCallback(UI.Image image);

class POIWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const POIWidget({Key key, this.poi, this.imageCreatedCallback})
      : super(key: key);
  final POI poi;
  final ImageCreatedCallback imageCreatedCallback;

  @override
  _POIWidgetState createState() => _POIWidgetState();
}

class _POIWidgetState extends State<POIWidget> {
  /**
   *  The only purpose of this widget is to provide an Image version of itself
   *  that can then be used in the MapBox map.
   */
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  Future<void> _capturePng() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    MediaQueryData queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double devicePixelRatio = queryData.devicePixelRatio;
    UI.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: devicePixelRatio);
    widget.imageCreatedCallback(image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VisibilityDetector(
      key: globalKey,
      onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
        var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
        debugPrint(
            'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
        if (visiblePercentage == 100) {
          _capturePng();
        }
      },
      child: RepaintBoundary(
        key: globalKey,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            color: widget.poi.iconBackgroundColor,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: widget.poi.iconSize.size * 2,
              height: widget.poi.iconSize.size * 2,
              child: widget.poi.iconName != null
                  ? IconManager.instance.getIconFromName(
                      widget.poi.iconName,
                      size: widget.poi.iconSize.size,
                      color: widget.poi.iconColor,
                    )
                  : IconManager.instance.iconMapPin,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works but I would recommend trying the answer above and extending `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` as a more elegant solution that wouldn't rely on third-party packages.